# Stateless hibernate session insert table which contains assosiation to another table

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

For insertion of bulk records into  the database i used the stateless session because it is fast with no caching and interceptors of hibernate don't get called with stateless session.But since stateless session doesn't take care of the associations.
 In my table i have the mapping to another table so how to i do the insert ?
I wanted to use HQL to insert , or what is the other availible option for the insertion of the rows on both the mapped tables also.
Please let me know the format for the inserts to the tables in HQL 
.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Loop through the associated collection and persist those first? NOTE: you may have to let hibernate fill those in with a fetch join query. It might be just less of a head ache to let go of the statelessness deal and do batched inserts with full persistence activated.

Comment: @Gimby i had compared the timings on using full persistance and also the stateless and found i could gain a lot using stateless so i would like to stick to stateless.And i found that the HQL insert in stateless are of syntax INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... format , so my question if mapped association is there how should we fill the foreign key and also one more question is (correct me if i am wrong) these DML inserts for the inherited object we can't access the base class variables in the insert .If my understanding is correct how will i set the values to the base class table ? a separate insert ?

Comment: Like I said: a manual fetch join query. Look that up in the hibernate documentation. I wouldn't use 'this is faster' as a reason to go do something though, the question is: is the performance when using full persistence unacceptable or not? What you're doing now is basically 'not using Hibernate', you might as well use plain old JDBC if getting the best performance is so important to you.

Comment: thanks @Gimby for the suggestions. I din't get actually what manual fetch join query during insert is ? can you please help me provide the link about it or example? thanks a ton in advance

Comment: This is the only documentation I find relevant for this discussion. If you want to do things your way, I suggest you research your way yourself. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html